# Laravel join query returns Null while raw query has a value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm stuck with a really stupid  query.

I tried to find the solution for like days, but nothing helped and so I don't find the answer.

I want to get the `newest` reaction from a table, to display the username.

First of all, these are my Database schemes:

`comments` (Has a model `Comment`)
[image: Comments]

`threads` (Has a model `Thread`)
[image: Threads]

So My raw query looks like this:

```
select `comments`.`username` from `comments` inner join `threads` on `comments`.`tid` = `threads`.`tid` where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null and `threads`.`cid` = '$categorie->id' order by `comments`.`posted_at` desc limit 1
```

A `var_dump()` of `$categorie->id` returns `int(3)` where the `3` stands for the categorie number.

When I execute the query (raw) in navicat, it returns this: 
[image: Output]

What is good, since that is the corract value it needs to return.

However when I rebuild this query in "Laravel-eloquent-style", the query looks like this:

```
Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->pluck('comments.username')
```

Be aware of that the query is build in a foreach loop and has an if-statement before. But that will be sown later on.

This does return nothing.

When I inspect elements, I just got nothing.

I tried the `DB::select(DB::raw('query'))`, but that doesn't work either.

I render my page in the ForumController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $forums = Forums::orderBy('disp_order', 'asc')->get();
        $categories = Categorie::orderBy('disp_order', 'asc')->get();

        return View::make('index')->with('forums', $forums)->with('categories', $categories);
    }
```

This works fine, and the view looks like this:

```
@foreach($forums as $forum)
<div class="panel-group col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: {{ $forum->color }};">

                <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fa-fw"></i>
                  <strong><a href="Forum-{{ Str::slug($forum->name) }}">{{ $forum->name }}</a></strong> 

              </div>
            <div id="forum4" class="panel-collapse collapse in">

            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Forum naam</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Topics</th>
                    <th class="">Laatste post info</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>

              @foreach($categories as $categorie)
              @if($categorie->fid == $forum->fid)
              <td class="topic-marker-forum">
                <i class="fa fa-comments fa-3x"></i>
              </td>

              <td class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div><a href="Categorie-{{ Str::slug($categorie->name) }}" title="{{ $categorie->name }}"><strong>{{ $categorie->name }}</strong></a></div>
                <div class=""><em>{{ $categorie->description }}</em></div>

              </td>

              <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-right"><span class="badge">{{ Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->remember(15)->count() }}</span></td>

              <td class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
                <div>
                  @if(Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->exists() && Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->exists())
                    <a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/Thread-{{ Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('date_posted', 'DESC')->pluck('slug') }}">{{ Helper::HTMLFilter(Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('date_posted', 'DESC')->pluck('title')) }}</a><br>

                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->pluck('posted_at'))->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}<br>

                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/User-{{ Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->pluck('comments.username') }}">{{ Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->pluck('comments.username') }}</a>
                  @else
                  <b>-</b>
                  @endif
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            @endforeach

            </tbody>
            </table></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

The strangest part is that this:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->pluck('posted_at'))->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}
```

Just works. Like nothing is wrong with that, when I call that item, it returns the correct value.

My Models are just normal;

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Comment extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'comments';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'uid');
    }

}
```

And

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Thread extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'threads';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: can you `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())` after you run the query, we can see the difference in raw queries

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/2W7QN Is what I get :) (From that query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Comment::with(['threads'=>function($query) use ($categorie){
                $query->where('threads.cid',$categorie->id)
                      ->whereNull('comments.deleted_at');
              }])
              ->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')
              ->limit(1)
              ->pluck('comments.username');
```

If you need -  were 'deleted_at' not null

```
->whereNotNull('comments.deleted_at');



DB::table('coments')
            ->join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')
            ->where('threads.cid',$categorie->id)
            ->whereNull('comments.deleted_at');
            ->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->pluck('comments.username');
```

Comment: The second code works like a charm. (After removing some typo's), the first code will I check too. If it works, I'll let you know in a comment. Thanks! <3

Comment: The first query in order to work, you have to define the model relationship between 'comments' and 'threads'